# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!-- of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, html, json

I am trying to following a tutorial get `json` to `ListView`,
this app just shows `Array` in `json`.
When I use the url source from [this site](http://api.learn2crack.com/android/jsonos/), the app works completely
but when I use local data `json` from my database, I always get an error.

The error is

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!-- of type java.lang.String 
cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

and show error in line 99 and 68

This my code

tes.html

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    { "android": [ { "ver": "1.5", "name": "Cupcake", "api": "API level 3" }, 
    { "ver": "1.6", "name": "Donut", "api": "API level 4" }, 
    { "ver": "2.0-2.1", "name": "Eclair", "api": "API level 5-7" }, 
    { "ver": "2.2", "name": "Froyo", "api": "API level 8" }, 
    { "ver": "2.3", "name": "Gingerbread", "api": "API level 9-10" }, 
    { "ver": "3.0-3.2", "name": "Honeycomb", "api": "API level 11-13" }, 
    { "ver": "4.0", "name": "Ice Cream Sandwich", "api": "API level 14-15" }, 
    { "ver": "4.1-4.3", "name": "JellyBean", "api": "API level 16-18" }, 
    { "ver": "4.4", "name": "KitKat", "api": "API level 19" } ] }
  <body>
</html>
```

This my JSONParse class

```
private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {  // THIS LINE 68 ERROR
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        ver = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.vers);
        name = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.name);
        api = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.api);
        //head = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.head);
        //note = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.note);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequestWithoutParams(url);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try {
            // Getting JSON Array from URL
            android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS); //THIS LINE 99 ERROR
            for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);
                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String ver = c.getString(TAG_VER);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String api = c.getString(TAG_API);
                // Adding value HashMap key => value
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(TAG_VER, ver);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_API, api);
                oslist.add(map);
                list=(ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),
                                              oslist,
                                              R.layout.list_v,
                                              new String[] { TAG_VER,TAG_NAME, TAG_API },
                                              new int[] { R.id.vers,R.id.name, R.id.api}
                                      );
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You Clicked at " + oslist.get(+position).get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

this my JSONObject

```
public JSONObject makeHttpRequestWithoutParams(String url) {
    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}
```

hope someone can help me thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're meant to have the html tags in that file? I would expect the file to be `test.json` with only a valid json object inside it

Comment: the error clearly says that your JSON is not valid. Check the format of your JSON once in a browser plugin before using it in your code

Comment: it will be helpful if you post your complete Logcat too ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "tes.html" (sic) source should not have any HTML tags in it. It should be JSON text only and probably should be named "test.json" instead (though the name of the file shouldn't really matter).

Proposed test.json:

```
{ "android": [ { "ver": "1.5", "name": "Cupcake", "api": "API level 3" }, 
{ "ver": "1.6", "name": "Donut", "api": "API level 4" }, 
{ "ver": "2.0-2.1", "name": "Eclair", "api": "API level 5-7" }, 
{ "ver": "2.2", "name": "Froyo", "api": "API level 8" }, 
{ "ver": "2.3", "name": "Gingerbread", "api": "API level 9-10" }, 
{ "ver": "3.0-3.2", "name": "Honeycomb", "api": "API level 11-13" }, 
{ "ver": "4.0", "name": "Ice Cream Sandwich", "api": "API level 14-15" }, 
{ "ver": "4.1-4.3", "name": "JellyBean", "api": "API level 16-18" }, 
{ "ver": "4.4", "name": "KitKat", "api": "API level 19" } ] }
```